# jarsigner doesn't work Ubuntu

Tags: android, testing, apk, jarsigner

I am trying to figure out how to sign apk with android debug key but when I use jarsigner after deleting meta from apk, I get the following error:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltOMv.png

Please help. I have java -version showing installed. Proof:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr1P8.png

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have `jarsigner` binary in your path, which ships with Java Developer Kit (JDK), and probably not with Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

You should install JDK properly on your system, so that all required binaries are configured properly.

1. [Install OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)
2. [Install Oracle JDK](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

**Or** If you have JDK in some other folder, you can add `<JDK>/bin` to `$PATH` environment variable:

```
export JDK_HOME=/path/to/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JDK_HOME/bin
```